# While trying to install rvm and ruby on ubuntu, curl is not recognized but is installed

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, curl, rvm

I'm installing rvm/ruby onto ubuntu 12.04 but I'm running into an issue.

rvm successfully installs, but afterwards when I try to do `rvm install ruby` I get this output:

```
RVM requires 'curl'. Install 'curl' first and try again.
Warning, new version of rvm available '', you are using older version '1.24.7'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 21: awk: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 22: dpkg: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 191: tr: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 210: head: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 204: sort: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 21: awk: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 22: dpkg: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 191: tr: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 248: find: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 21: awk: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 22: dpkg: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 191: tr: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 210: head: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 204: sort: command not found
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-2.0.0-p353.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for .
Requirements support for ruby-2.0.0-p353 is not implemented yet,
report a bug here => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

The thing is, curl is installed:

```
# curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I can run curl no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a default curl install packaged with Ubuntu, or did you install with apt-get?

Comment: I believe it's the one I got with apt-get, because using apt-get install curl gives a message saying it is already installed.

Comment: Newer issues with NVM need Node's version of `which` removed: https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/languages-frameworks/ruby/#rvm-requires-curl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### UPDATE *2014-09*

If you'are trying to install RVM system wide, preferred is to use a normal user (not root) for RVM installation.

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

$ rvm requirements
$ rvm install 2.1.3
$ rvm use --default 2.1.3
```

Also, perhaps off-topic, for a prod server and to replace default 1.8.7 (system wide) you could do it without RVM:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
$ cd ruby-build
$ ./install.sh

$ ruby-build 2.1.3 /usr/local
```

Comment: He's already on the stable version of rvm (1.24.7) but I think you hit the nail on the head with the `rvm requirements` recommendation. Nice job.

Comment: Hmm well I tried completely removing rvm and reinstalling it per this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm but I've found that after i do `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and relaunch the terminal it is unable to find a file at the location when I do `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`... I'm doing this as the root user (in ~ of root), is that wrong?

Comment: I believe the first time I was doing this I was getting rvm from `apt-get install rvm`

Comment: Are you trying to install RVM system wide? Preferred is to use a normal user (not root) for RVM installation. If you just want to replace 1.8.7 system Ruby for a production server i can paste the steps for that.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to go system wide. I spoke with a friend this morning who told me the same thing you did, I tried as a normal user and it worked fine. Go ahead and make your comment an answer if you want and I'll mark it as the winner.